# file_get_contents works but file_put_contents doesn't

Tags: php

I'm on win7, xampp. This works:

```
$path = '../HOME/01.html';  
$cnt = file_get_contents($path);
echo $cnt;
```

This doesn't work:

```
$path = '../HOME/01.html'; 
$cnt = 'lorem ipsum';       
file_put_contents($path, $cnt);
```

There is no error or warning, simply `01.html` is without the content.

Comment: hope thats not the actual code, as it has syntax errors

Comment: Do you have permission to write there? Is HOME really all caps?

Comment: @chiliNUT, `HOME`  is all caps. Permission - I set it by right click on `HOME - Properties - ... all permissions to all users`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the [manual page](https://www.php.net/file_put_contents):

> This function returns the number of bytes that were written to the file, or FALSE on failure.

You should check to make sure that the return value is not `false`:

```
if (file_put_contents($path, $cnt) === false) {
    // handle error
}
```

However I would assume that the vast majority of cases are a lack of permissions to write to the file. Fortunately PHP has a [function to check that](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php):

```
if (!is_writable($path)) {
    // No permission to write
}
```

So, putting these two together you could do something like:

```
if (file_put_contents($path, $cnt) === false) {
    if (!is_writable($path)) {
        return "You do not have permission to write to $path";
    }
    return "An unknown error occurred while writing to $path";
}
return "successfully wrote to $path";
```